# codefirst - model changes commands

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am confused about one thing that how and in which order should we execute the commands in project manager console when a new model and modify the existing model requires to update the database.

```
1) Enable-migrations
2) Add-Migration 
3) Update-database
```

I am presuming that on the base of model changes or new model, we require these commands to be executed in the mentioned order each time. Kindly guide me in this regard. –

Comment: http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable migration to your project **for first time**, run

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

If migration is enabled and you changed your model and want to affect changes to your database run

```
PM> Add-Migration [migration-name]
PM> Update-Database
```

There are more useful switches for above commands that you can find at [EF Migrations Command Reference](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/).

Comment: Thanks Masoud for the help.